# How to put button in SAPUI5 quickview?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a **sapui5** **QuickView**, which looks something like this:
[image]

```
    <QuickView id="quickView">
      <QuickViewPage pageId="PageId123">
        <QuickViewGroup>
        <QuickViewGroupElement label="Material" value="{Material}" type="{sap.m.QuickViewGroupElementType.text}"></QuickViewGroupElement>
        </QuickViewGroup>
       </QuickViewPage>
     </QuickView>
```

Now, I want to add a button in bottom of Quickview. Is it possible? I tried adding

```
<Button icon="sap-icon://action"> </<Button>
```

But this does not work somehow. Is there any way I can add button? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

According to [Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/quickview/)

> The quick view is similar to a popover, but has a predefined structure, a fixed set of UI elements, and automatic UI rendering.
>
> (...)
>
> Do not use the quick view if:
>
> - You want to provide information in a way other than displaying it in groups.

Basically this can be understood checking the `Type` of the following aggregations:

- `pages` from class [`sap.m.QuickView`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.QuickView)
- `groups` from class [`sap.m.QuickViewPage`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.QuickViewPage)
- `elements` from class [`sap.m.QuickViewGroup`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.QuickViewGroup)

Finally, class [`sap.m.QuickViewGroupElement`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.QuickViewGroupElement) is not a container that allows you to add controls (like a Button) inside it.

So, you should use a Popover [like in this sample](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Popover/sample/sap.m.sample.Popover) from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use a View. Put a button first and then add a QuickView as fragment. There is an example in the UI5 Demo Kit.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.QuickViewCard/sample/sap.m.sample.QuickViewCard

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This may well answer the question, however, link only answers are discouraged. Please consider adding some code to demonstrate how this answers the question.